# Subset strings in R

Tags: r, string, subset

One of the strings in my vector (df$location1) is the following:

```
Potomac, MD 20854\n(39.038266, -77.203413)
```

Rest of the data in the vector follow same pattern. I want to separate each component of the string into a separate data element and put it in new columns like: df$city, df$state, etc.

So far I have been able to isolate the lat. long. data into a separate column by doing the following:

```
df$lat.long <- gsub('.*\\\n\\\((.*)\\\)','\\\1',df$location1)
```

I was able to make it work by looking at other codes online but I don't fully understand it. I understand the regex pattern but don't understand the "\\1" part. Since I don't understand it in full I have been unable to use it to subset other parts of this same string.

- What's the best way to subset data like this?
- Is using regex a good way to do this? What other ways should I be looking into?

I have looked into splitting the string after a comma, subset using regex, using scan() function and to many other variations. Now I am all confused. Thx

Comment: `"\\1"` refers to the first group, groups are defined by parenthesis in the pattern, replacing the match by a group is a convenient way to extract a substring, usually used when your pattern matches the full string, try `gsub(".....(.....(....))","\\1","grp0 grp1 grp2")` and `gsub(".....(.....(....))","\\2","grp0 grp1 grp2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `strsplit` or `data.table::tstrsplit`(`strsplit` + `transpose`):

```
> x <- 'Potomac, MD 20854\n(39.038266, -77.203413)'
> data.table::tstrsplit(x, ', |\\n\\(|\\)')
[[1]]
[1] "Potomac"

[[2]]
[1] "MD 20854"

[[3]]
[1] "39.038266"

[[4]]
[1] "-77.203413"
```

More generally, you can do this:

```
library(data.table)
df[c('city', 'state', 'lat', 'long')] <- tstrsplit(df$location1, ', |\\n\\(|\\)')
```

The pattern `', |\\n\\(|\\)'` tells `tstrsplit` to split by `", "`, `"\n("` or `")"`.

In case you want to sperate state and zip and cite names may contain spaces, You can try a two-step way:

```
# original split (keep city names with space intact)
df[c('city', 'state', 'lat', 'long')] <- tstrsplit(df$location1, ', |\\n\\(|\\)')
# split state and zip
df[c('state', 'zip')] <- tstrsplit(df$state, ' ')
```

Comment: I want to assign each component into a separate variable. When I do df$city1 <- data.table::tstrsplit(x, ',') I get the following error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, city1, value = list(c("Potomac", "Rockville",  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 25535

Comment: @pyuser181, You can create all  variables simutaneously with the general solution shown in the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation. It all makes sense. I even combined www's separation logic, but it trips in cases like below where there are spaces in city names. e.g.: Silver Spring, MD 20902\n(39.042613, -77.046758). So I tried separating by ", " , "[[:space:]]" , "\n(", and ")".  I am trying to separate in to city, state, zip, lat.long (e.g.39.038266, -77.203413).

Comment: @pyuser181, I did not anticipate that. See my edited at the end of the original answer that works for city names containing spaces.

Comment: Thank you.I don't know why I did not think of that. I guess I was trying to do all in one line. I have marked it as solved.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use the `separate` function from the `tidyr` package (part of the `tidyverse` package).

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data frame
dat <- data.frame(Data = "Potomac, MD 20854\n(39.038266, -77.203413)",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat
#                                         Data
# 1 Potomac, MD 20854\n(39.038266, -77.203413)

# Separate the Data column
dat2 <- dat %>%
  separate(Data, into = c("City", "State", "Zip", "Latitude", "Longitude"),
           sep = ", |\\\n\\(|\\)|[[:space:]]")
dat2
#      City State   Zip  Latitude  Longitude
# 1 Potomac    MD 20854 39.038266 -77.203413
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution using tidyverse. it worked except when cities had spaces in their names. e.g.: Silver Spring, MD 20902\n(39.042613, -77.046758). I am trying to separate in to city, state, zip, lat.long (e.g.39.038266, -77.203413). Since the space in city name conflicts with space in long. lat. is it best to separate these first and then combine lat. long again into a new column if I really want them together (e.g.39.038266, -77.203413).

Comment: You can adjust the `sep` argument based on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
read.table(text= trimws(gsub(",+", " ", gsub("[, \n()]", ",", dat$Data))), 
  header = FALSE, col.names = c("City", "State", "Zip", "Latitude", "Longitude"), 
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#    City State   Zip Latitude Longitude
#1 Potomac    MD 20854 39.03827 -77.20341
```

Answer (score 0):

So this process might be a little longer, but for me it makes things clear. As opposed to using breaks, below I identify values by using a specific regex for each value I want. I make a vector of regex to extract each value, a vector for the variable names, then use a loop to extract and create the dataframe from those vectors.

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

rgexVec <- c("[\\w\\s-]+(?=,)", 
         "[A-Z]{2}", 
         "\\d+(?=\\n)", 
         "[\\d-\\.]+(?=,)", 
         "[\\d-\\.]+(?=\\))")
varNames <- c("city", 
          "state", 
          "zip", 
          "lat", 
          "long")
map2_dfc(varNames, rgexVec, function(vn, rg) {
  extractedVal <- stri_extract_first_regex(value, rg) %>% as.list()
  names(extractedVal) <- vn
  extractedVal %>% as_tibble()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

`\\1` is a `back reference` in regex. It is similar to a wildcard (*) that will grab all instances of your search term, not just the first one it finds.

Comment: That' was also something I did not know. Thank you.